# Arduino RGB LED code issues

Tags: arduino, rgb, led, lcd

I'm having some trouble with my arduino code. My code has 3 potentiometers that alter each individual colors in a LED, and a button that will fade through red, green, blue (when pressed, it cycles once and when held it continuously cycles). It used to work, but when I tried to add a LCD screen that displays each RGB value, it stopped working. I know it's not written the best, it's just an experimental code as I just got an arduino and am just trying to familiarize myself. When I plug it in, the LCD prints all white squares on the top row and the led is red with flashing blue, and nothing happens when I press the button or turn the pots. Here is the code, any help is appreciated:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

int potPin1 = 14 ; // select the input pin for the potentiometer, ANALOG
int potPin2 = 15;
int potPin3 = 16; 

int potVal1 = 0; // variable to store the value coming from the sensor
int potVal2 = 0;
int potVal3 = 0; 

int ledPin1 = 6; // select the pin for the LED, PWM for analogWrite capability?
int ledPin2 = 9;
int ledPin3 = 10;

int buttonPin = 7;
int buttonState= LOW;

String printCycleVal1 = (""); //print values when cycling colors
String printCycleVal2 = ("");
String printCycleVal3 = ("");

String printVal1 = ("");//print values when not cycling colors
String printVal2 = ("");
String printVal3 = ("");

int val1 = 0; //values to store rgb colors in
int val2 = 0;
int val3 = 0;

void setup() 
{
  pinMode(potPin1, INPUT);
  pinMode(potPin2, INPUT);
  pinMode(potPin3, INPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  lcd.begin(2,16);
}

void loop()
{
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("RGB Values: ");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);

  potVal1 = analogRead(potPin1);
  val1 = map(potVal1, 0, 1023, 0, 255);
  analogWrite(ledPin1, val1);
  printVal1 += ("V1: ");
  printVal1 += (val1);
  printVal1 += (" | ");

  potVal2 = analogRead(potPin2);
  val2 = map(potVal2, 0, 1023, 0, 255);
  analogWrite(ledPin2, val2);
  printVal2 += ("V2: ");
  printVal2 += (val2);
  printVal2 += (" | ");

  potVal3 = analogRead(potPin3);
  val3 = map(potVal3, 0, 1023, 0, 255);
  analogWrite(ledPin3, val3);
  printVal3 = ("V3: ");
  printVal3 += (val3);

  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  while (buttonState == HIGH)
    cycle();
}

void cycle() {
  setColourRgb(0, 0, 0);
  unsigned int rgbColour[3];

  // Start off with red.
  rgbColour[0] = 255;
  rgbColour[1] = 0;
  rgbColour[2] = 0;  

  // Choose the colours to increment and decrement.
  for (int decColour = 0; decColour < 3; decColour += 1) {
    int incColour = decColour == 2 ? 0 : decColour + 1;

    // cross-fade the two colours.
    for(int i = 0; i < 255; i += 1) {
      rgbColour[decColour] -= 1;
      rgbColour[incColour] += 1;

      setColourRgb(rgbColour[0], rgbColour[1], rgbColour[2]);
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0,0);
      lcd.print("RGB Values: ");
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);

      printCycleVal1 += ("V1: ");
      printCycleVal1 += (rgbColour[0]);
      printCycleVal1 += (" | ");

      printCycleVal2 += ("V2: ");
      printCycleVal2 += (rgbColour[1]);
      printCycleVal2 += (" | ");

      printCycleVal3 += ("V3: ");
      printCycleVal3 += (rgbColour[2]);
      delay(5);
    }
    buttonState = LOW;   n
  }
}

void setColourRgb(unsigned int red, unsigned int green, unsigned int blue) {
  analogWrite(ledPin1, red);
  analogWrite(ledPin2, green);
  analogWrite(ledPin3, blue);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the LCD screen with demo code by itself and then to integrate it into your existing project? That is that way I normally get new pieces of hardware working with my Arduino projects.

Comment: So you have a "loose" "n" on line 112, in the cycle() function on the line near it's end that is `buttonState = LOW;   n`, that may just be a transcription error onto stackoverflow, not the real problem, the compiler would have already told you that if it was in your actual code...?

Comment: Please edit the question to include what board you are using.  Also expand what you mean by "it stopped working".  Do the LED's light at all?  Does it just not cycle?

Comment: the loose 'n' was probably just from copying it to here, I always verify before I upload. Updated with a description of the problem.

Comment: Have you been able to get the LCD screen working with demo code only, before trying to integrate it into you existing project? Also, knowing what type of Arduino board you are using would be helpful.

Comment: It's a Rev3, I figured out I had the button set up wrong and that's why the LED was doing weird things.

Comment: UPDATE: redid wiring, now the led just puts out a purple color and doesn't do anything when I push the button/turn the pots. The screen prints "RGB Values:" and no line on the bottom. any help please!

Comment: Had a friend look at it, apparently arduino code doesn't like strings and I need to use an array of characters?

Comment: there is not a line lcd.print() for the rgb numbers.  Computers dont like or dislike.

Comment: I would try using the starter code that surely is available with your LCD screen without and RGB LED stuff, just get that working and understand how your LCD works and make sure it does in fact work correctly before trying to integrate it with your existing code for your project.